# Authentication API call for V1 access token doesn't work in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, accesstoken

I'm trying to get the v1 access token from a legacy package . Reference this [DOC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/get-access-token.html?q=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN)

It is pretty straightforward

```
POST https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
}
```

But strangely, this is the response I got from the call

```
{
    "message": "clientId is required",
    "errorcode": 10002,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

I confirm that I'm using the client credentials from the legacy package and have already filled in all the values. Anyone have an idea what happened?

Comment: Just so we're all clear, you've replaced the values for `YOUR_SUBDOMAIN`, `YOUR_CLIENT_ID`, and `YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET` correct? Don't laugh, you'd be surprised ...

Comment: @BillMote Yes, I am sure I did. That's why I mentioned that in the end of my question post. I even tried to use the client credentials with oath v2 token and got the error message implied I need to go for the /v1/requestToken endpoint lol

Comment: @BillMote Can you let me know what I am missing here? I am really curious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't follow the payload format in the doc, that's why the authentication API call didn't run successfully.

This is the payload format in the doc for v1 access token

```
{
    "clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
}
```

While I used the payload format in v2 access token for the authentication call

```
{
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
}
```

That silly mistake caused the response above in my question post.